# Visual Studio Templates - adding additional pre-existing projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I'm working on a Visual Studio template where the generated project relies on a number of references, which happen to be other projects under source control.

The question is how do I set this up in my ProjectGroup template?  For example, if I have an already existing project at "C:\Stuff\MyUtilityProject\Utility.csproj" with a single file (Tools.cs) that I want to add to my template, how would I go about this?

Here's what my vstempalte looks like.  FYI - I am having no issues with the ProjectTemplateLink or creation of the Solution folder, just in adding the pre-existing Utility.csproj to my new solution:

Thanks in advance!

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>MySampleSolution</Name>
    <Description>My Test Project</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <SolutionFolder Name="Content">
                <Project File="C:\Stuff\MyUtilityProject\Utility.csproj">
                    <ProjectItem>Tools.cs</ProjectItem>
                </Project>
            </SolutionFolder>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyWorkingTemplate">
            MyWorkingTemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: You found any solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Is the idea to create a project template that others in your organziation can use which includes important other dependency projects (e.g. utility libs, data access libs, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I know in **Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate)** is to create a **project/solution** from your template, add the ***.cs** files you need and then export the solution again using the template export wizard.

For the library you have you can create an **item template** rather than a project/solution template - this allows to add it using **add -> new item** from the context menu in the solution explorer of Visual Studio.

To create an **item template**, open your solution, then use **File -> Export template...** and select **item template** as export type once the wizard dialog opens.

Ensure that you have the "import" checkbox checked on the wizard, otherwise it will not be automatically installed after you've created it.

Answer (score 1):

You could [host your own NuGet feed](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) (or use [the NuGet capabilities](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/native-nuget-support-in-teamcity/) of [TeamCity](http://jetbrains.com/teamcity) or a private [MyGet](http://myget.org) feed. Then you would just need to [package your utility project as a NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) and add it to your project template as described here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

[Visual Studio - Programmatically configure solution for source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735715/visual-studio-programmatically-configure-solution-for-source-control)

EDIT:

I have been looking around an seen this rather interesting project, it seems to export solutions rather than projects which may or may not be a better idea. I particularly like the part at the end that says it will strip out source control so you get a clean project. I know this is not the exact answer you would like but it is worth a look ;)

http://flux88.com/blog/exporting-visual-studio-solutions-with-solutionfactory/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not quite - we're looking to use an existing solution template vs. building this programatically.

Comment: Sorry my fault for not reading, there seems to be little on this about the web but I found a rather interesting project above that may be a step in the right direction, supports multiple projects and strips source control for output!

Comment: I actually looked at that one - the only sticking point is that it's fine if your template includes multiple new projects, but does not work if you need to reference existing projects - i.e. we have several solutions that all include a shared library project (not copies).  Thanks!